# How to capture arguments of original function after applying 'setattr' to it?

Tags: python, python-2.x, built-in

I have a module in a project that loads before anything else and this module needs to add custom logic to a list of functions that I retrieve from database. To add this custom logic I use builtin python function setattr.

Also, people of the same project want to capture arguments for some of the functions that are in the same list. To capture arguments they use inspect.getcallargs function. However, instead of getting arguments of original function they get the arguments of the wrapper function.

I understand why this happens but don't have a solution for the problem.

My decorator/wrapper looks like the following:

```
def func_decorator(func, some_other_params):
    def func_to_return(*args, **kwargs):
        # some code
        payload = func(*args, **kwargs)
        # some other code
        return payload
    return func_to_return
```

So, in the function that goes over the list of functions to decorate I have something that looks like the following:

```
def add_custom_logic_to_funcs:
    ....
    for func_name in funcs:
        func = getattr(func_class, func_name)
        setattr(func_class, func_name, func_decorator(func, some_params))
```

If let's say original function looks like the following:

```
class A:
    def(self, x=None, y=None, z=1):
        #some code
```

Calling inspect.getcallargs results in returnning {'args': (some object at 0x000000001BCA8C50,), 'kwargs': {}} instead of {'self': some object at 0x000000001BCA8C50, 'x': None, 'y': None, 'z': 1}

Comment: (if this is Python 2, `class A` should be inheritng from `object`. If it is not, your project is using 2001 Python, and it should not. Really.

Comment: It inherits from 'object'. I just didn't include it in the skeleton of example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need two things there - 
First is that your decorator is itself decorated with `functools.wraps()`, so that some metadata on the decorated function is added to the decorated function:

```py
from functools import decorator

def func_decorator(func, some_other_params):
    @wraps(func)
    def func_to_return(*args, **kwargs):
        # some code
        payload = func(*args, **kwargs)
        # some other code
        return payload
    return func_to_return
```

That however, don't make `inspect.getcallargs` to reflect the decorated signature. 
Instead of that, you have to use `inspect.signature` - which returns a richer `Signature` object, but that have a `.parameters` attribute that will look like the return from `.getcallargs`:

```py
In [26]: def deco(func): 
    ...:     @wraps(func) 
    ...:     def wrapper(*args, **kw): 
    ...:         return func(*args, **kw) 
    ...:     return wrapper 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [27]: class A: 
    ...:     @deco 
    ...:     def b(self, a, b=2): 
    ...:         pass 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [28]: inspect.signature(A().b).parameters                                                                                                                                                   
Out[28]: mappingproxy({'a': <Parameter "a">, 'b': <Parameter "b=2">})

In [29]: inspect.signature(A.b).parameters                                                                                                                                                     
Out[29]: 
mappingproxy({'self': <Parameter "self">,
              'a': <Parameter "a">,
              'b': <Parameter "b=2">})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
My bad, I do have @wraps just forgot to include it. Also, looks like inspect.signature isn't available in python 2.7. I also don't have funcigs as a part of our venv.

Comment: No - sorry - this is for Python as it is now. Python 2.7 is 2009 Python.